# I don't understand string in c#

Tags: c#

As someone who's only ever used c++, i'm so confused. I've gone over different explanations but i still can't seem to understand it. Why do i, for example, need to check if a string is a string? (the tryparse method) If it's a number obviously its an int...right?? So for example my current code takes in age in one function and outputs it in the main function. I tried converting it to int but i got error cs0019: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of 'int' and 'string'

```
public static string GetAge()
{
  Console.WriteLine("\nPlease input age > ");

int age = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  if (age == "") 
  {
    do {
      Console.Write("Invalid input. Please try again > ");
      age = Console.ReadLine();
       } while ( age == "");
  }
  return age;

}

static void Main (){

Console.WriteLine("\nPlease note\nThis program is only applicable for users born between 1999 and 2010");

string name = GetName();
string year = GetYear();
int age = GetAge();
```

And then i also get this error cs0029:Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' (line 49 which is return age) and error cs0029: cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' for line 58 (int age =GetAge();)

Comment: You are initializing the variable `age` as an integer. As such it can never be a string and hence not compared to a string.

Comment: Age is an int. You are comparing it with "" hence the error

Comment: @Atk Is that not a reasonable thing to do if im trying to say that if no value is entered then carry out xyz command?

Comment: No it isn't. The code is gonna break at the parse method if no value is entered. You have to use tryparse.

Comment: `Int32.Parse` and `Int32.TryParse` don't check if a string is a string.  They *convert* a string to an integer, analogous to C++'s `std::stoi`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int.Parse` will throw an exception if it fails.  I would modify your loop to this:

```
int age; 
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age))
    Console.Write("Invalid input. Please try again > ");
return age;
```

`int.TryParse` will return `true` upon success.

Also change the method definition to return an `int` instead:

```
public static int GetAge()
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked. Could you please explain it in simple terms? I've read the online explanations and they tend to go over my head. I like writing logbooks explaining my code so i can make sure i understand it well.

Comment: @TübaËs Sure.  `int.Parse` throws an exception if it fails to parse the parameter.  I would only use this if I knew the parse will succeed.  In any other case, such as user input, there's no guarantee of success. `int.TryParse` is preferred here because it will _not_ throw an exception and instead return false.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what do you want and why. :-)

You don't need to check string is string.

int.Parse will throwing an exception, when the input is not a valid integer, but you can use TryParse, what is returns a boolean and does not throw exception.

In C# you can't compare integers and strings, you must convert it first.

Your GetAge method returns integer, but the return type declared as string.

```
public static int GetAge()
{
    int age;
    Console.Write("\nPlease input age > ");
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int age))
    {
        Console.Write("Invalid input. Please try again > ");
    };
    return age;
}

static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease note\nThis program is only applicable for users born between 1999 and 2010");
    string name = GetName();
    string year = GetYear();
    int age = GetAge();
}
```